# Валидация формы не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery

Главное там где я это стащил -  работает а у меня нет =( не получается сделать. Подскажите как сделать так чтобы заработало.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
function valid(form){
 var error = false;
 var name = form.email.value;
 var name = form.phone.value;
  if(email == "" || email == " "){
     error = "Вы не ввели email";
    }
      else if (phone == ""){
        error = "Вы не ввели телефон";
      }
        if(error){
            alert(error);
        } 
} 
});
```

```css
form{
 padding: 20px;
 background-color: #fff;
 max-width: 320px;
 margin: auto;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
 
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <form id="form" method="post" name="">
  <input  type="text" name="email" placeholder="Введите email" i />
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон"  /> <br />
  <input type="button" onclick="valid(document.getElementById('form'))" name="submit" value="Готово" />
 </form>
```

Comment: Лучше бы помог чем язвить

Comment: Для вашей элементарной проверки не нужен js. Достаточно в инпутах прописать атрибут `required`.

Comment: Вы где-то стащили код, программировать не умеете или не хотите, но зато хотите, чтобы вам его переделали так, чтобы работал? Обратитесь на фриланс-биржу.

Comment: @karman помогаю тут тем, кто сам делает и не получается, а не тому, кто не разбирается и просто копипастит код без вникания

Answer (score 5):

1. `JQuery` здесь не нужен.
2. Вот в этих строках ошибки:

`var name = form.email.value; //должно быть email=`

`var name = form.phone.value; //должно быть phone=`

Вот работающий код:

```html
<script>
 function valid(form){
  var error = false;
  var email = form.email.value;
  var phone = form.phone.value;
   if(email == "" || email == " "){
   error = "Вы не ввели email";
  }
    else if (phone == ""){
      error = "Вы не ввели телефон";
    }
      if(error){
          alert(error);
      } 
 } 
</script>

<form id="form" method="post" name="">
 <input  type="text" name="email" placeholder="Введите email" i />
 <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон"  /> <br />
 <input type="button" onclick="valid(document.getElementById('form'))" name="submit" value="Готово" />
</form>
```

Comment: В принципе, @Nagibaka все верно сказал.

Comment: Не стоит давать ответы на такие вопросы. Этим вы провоцируете человека на дальнейшие поиски халявы.

Answer (score 4):

Уберите первую и последнюю строку в вашем js-коде. Или вынесите функцию из `$(document).ready(function() {})`
У вас проблема с областью видимости - ваш обработчик нажатия на кнопка сабмита не видит функцию валидации.

Добавил решение на jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/g1qh8zom/4/

```js
// Validation function
function valid(form) {
  var isValidMail = form.find('[name=email]').val().length <= 1 ? alert("Вы не ввели email") : true;
  var isValidName = form.find('[name=phone]').val().length <= 1 ? alert("Вы не ввели телефон") : true;
  return isValidMail && isValidName ? true : false;
}

// On load
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#form').on('submit', function() {
    return valid($(this));
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" method="post" name="">
  <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Введите email" value="" />
  <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Введите телефон" value="" />
  <br />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Готово" />
</form>
```

Comment: Я его вынес, но это не помогло

Comment: Не стоит давать ответы на такие вопросы. Этим вы провоцируете человека на дальнейшие поиски халявы.